# Display only the last submission per user of a webform in views

Tags: views, users, webforms

I have a webform. I want to create a view of all submissions to the webform, but I only want to display the last submission for any particular user based on the "Webform submissions: Completed" field. i.e. I only want one row per user if they have submitted the form multiple times.

Is it possible to create a filter that will do that?

Answer (score 1):

I have worked out a simple solution to this - the [Views Distinct module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_distinct)

Answer (score 1):

Limit the Submission view result to 1. And sort "submission ID" by decending order.

Comment: But that would only return a single result. I want all form submissions, but only the latest one if a user has submitted a form more than once.